# How to assign a value to a variable given as parameter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, parameters

```
def function(x):
    x = 4
variable = 0
function(variable)
print(variable)
```

This would output 0 but is there a way that it outputs 4? And also it should be without return.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Comment: **TL;DR**: don't.

Comment: Obligatory read: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'd suggest you take a look to this nice explanation about python [names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html). Now, one possible way to achieve what you want would be using a mutable structure as a dictionary, so you can pass your variable inside, something similar to this would do it:

```
def function(dct):
    dct['variable'] = 4

dct = {
    'variable': 0
}

function(dct)
print(dct['variable'])
```

More info can be found in [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html)